# Is ‘may’ interchangeable with ‘will’ here?

Tags: verbs

Can *may(verb)* be interchanged with *will* in this

> O believers! Bow down, prostrate yourselves, worship your Lord, and do ˹what is˺ good so that you **may** be successful. (22:77)

Although *may* shows uncertainty while *will* show certainty, may is interchangeable with will as per [Britannica.com](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/may):

> May (formal + old- fashioned)
>
> used to indicate the reason for something or the purpose of something
>
> Example:We exercise so that we may [=will] be strong and healthy.

Comment: *May* has other definitions as well…

Comment: The usage here seems to fit the definition from Britannica.

Comment: Could anyone kindly give me a complete answer, I need to use that somewhere else.

Comment: Hello, AbduRahman. '... _may_ is interchangeable with _will_ as per Britannica.com' – **but not usually**. 'I may come on Tuesday' ≠ 'I will come on Tuesday'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sense of 'may' is one of many:

> **may** 14. [modal verb]
>
> If you do something so that a particular thing may happen, you do it
> so that there is an opportunity for that thing to happen.
>
> - ...*the need for more surgeons so that patients may be treated more quickly.*
> - *The door is shut so that no one may overhear what is said.*

[[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/may)]

'Might' is used in the same way.

'Being obedient to God, positioning yourselves so that He considers it safe to bless you' can be equated with '... and He will bless you' with faith in a righteous and loving God. Of course, books have been written on why there often seems to be a delay, and His choice of how to bless you.

Comment: Thanks, I think it would be better to side with certainty rather than uncertainty because it may lead to question such as " Is God Uncertain?".

Comment: But His ways are beyond human understanding. Men and women have died heroically for their faith, which many would fail to see as being successful.